# Names of specific galaxies in Hubble's XDF

Tags: galaxy, telescope, hubble-telescope

I'm working on a little side project that traces and identifies galaxies in Hubble's XDF using OpenCV.

This is my current progress with tracing the more prominent galaxies:
[image]
[image]

**I was wondering if there was some kind of database for the galaxies that appear in the XDF.** Like their scientific names, coordinates, distances, and etc.

Here's a link to the image I am using for the project: https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/hubble/science/xdf.html

Answer (score 2):

The [XDF data release](https://archive.stsci.edu/prepds/xdf/)
has images in FITS format, which includes a world coordinate system to map image coordinates to celestial coordinates.
Then you can [query SIMBAD](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fcoo)
to see what galaxies are near those coordinates.

For example, I loaded a WFC 60mas/pixel image into a FITS viewer,
which indicates that the face-on spiral at center left of the PR image
is near J2000 3h32m40.8s -27d46m16s.
(To align the PR image with the equatorial coordinate grid, rotate it about 50 degrees clockwise.)
SIMBAD found [this galaxy](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=%407814928&Name=%5bRTG2015%5d%2024587) at that location, B-band magnitude 22.

To do this in Python code, you could try using
[astropy.wcs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/wcs/index.html)
to get celestial coordinates from the FITS image and
[astroquery.simbad](http://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simbad/simbad.html)
to look up objects of interest.

Answer (score 1):

After speaking to some people on Astronomy discords, they told me about SINBAD.

http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/